# DAX Calculate Last Week when This Week selected

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would be hugely appreciative of any help.  I made a dashboard for my client and I put a Week Period selector on the top. This is not using any date calcs but just importing the data and assigning it a Week No - 1-52.  This is also grouped into a period.  The user is meant to select the week they want to look at on this selector and the dashboard should reflect what is in the selected week and the previous week. There is a brand slicer (as there are 2 brands) on the dashboard too and this is also meant to be taken into account.

I have created a measure to calculate the current week and the previous week:

```
01M - Current Week = MAXX('01 - SKU Downloads','01 - SKU Downloads'[Week])
```

And

```
02M - Last Week = MAXX('01 - SKU Downloads','01 - SKU Downloads'[Week]-1)
```

These seem to be working.

I am currently trying to create a measure that show's last weeks units regardless of the brand (although I want to add it in when I have this working).

```
14M - Units Last Week = VAR
                        LastWeek = [02M - Last Week]
                    RETURN
                        CALCULATE(SUM('01 - SKU Downloads'[Units This Year]),'01 - SKU Downloads'[Week]=LastWeek)
```

This works when no filters (brand or week) are being applied but as soon as the week filter is applied I get a (blank).  I have tried numerous combinations of FILTER, ALL, CALCULATE but I just don't seem to be able to get it to work.

Update
The DAX below returns the correct numbers by week but it ignores the brand slicer but is correct if I hard code it:

```
14M - Units Last Week = VAR
                        LastWeek = MAXX('01 - SKU Downloads','01 - SKU Downloads'[Week]-1)
                    RETURN
                        CALCULATE(SUM('01 - SKU Downloads'[Units This Year]),
                                        FILTER(ALL('01 - SKU Downloads'),'01 - SKU Downloads'[Week]=LastWeek),
                                        FILTER(ALL('01 - SKU Downloads'), '01 - SKU Downloads'[Brand'] = "BRAND1"))
```

BRAND1 is hard coded but want it responsive to the brand slicer!?

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated.

Alex

Comment: I think the problem would be because of the result of the intersection of two conditions Slicer = SelectedWeek (from visualization) and '01 - SKU Downloads'[Week] = LastWeek (from CALCULATE) is null. There are no rows that meet both conditions. Inside CALCULATE add a CALCULATE modifier to remove the filter coming from the slicer in such a way that '01 - SKU Downloads'[Week] = LastWeek returns a result. I clarify that this opinion is based on reading because there is no data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedack.  The following `code`14M - Units Last Week = VAR
                        LastWeek = MAXX('01 - SKU Downloads','01 - SKU Downloads'[Week]-1)
                    RETURN
                        CALCULATE(SUM('01 - SKU Downloads'[Units This Year]),
                                        FILTER(ALL('01 - SKU Downloads'),'01 - SKU Downloads'[Week]=LastWeek),
                                        FILTER(ALL('01 - SKU Downloads'), '01 - SKU Downloads'[Brand'] = "BRAND1"))`code` brand hard coded but would be responsive to the brand slicer.

Comment: 14M - Units Last Week = VAR LastWeek = MAXX('01 - SKU Downloads','01 - SKU Downloads'[Week]-1) RETURN CALCULATE( SUM( '01 - SKU Downloads'[Units This Year] ), ALL('01 - SKU Downloads'[Week]), '01 - SKU Downloads'[Week] = LastWeek )